# Tkinter Frame Disappears after adding a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have two frames in the root. And I want to add a button in one of the frames. Both frames have different background colours. When I try to add a button in any of them, the frame that contains the button disappears.

### Without button

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("ABC")

Rf = Frame(root, width=100, height=800, bg="black")
Rf.pack(side=RIGHT)

Lf = Frame(root, width=1500, height=800, bg="green")
Lf.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Which results in...

[image]

### With button

But after adding the button, with the following code...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("ABC")

Rf = Frame(root, width=100, height=800, bg="black")
Rf.pack(side=RIGHT)

Lf = Frame(root, width=1500, height=800, bg="green")
Lf.pack(side=LEFT)

b1 = Button (Rf, text="Load", fg="red", bg="black")
b1.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

I get...

[image]

Now the button is visible but the frame and background colours are gone. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think the frame is gone, but the background color is reset to gray.  Try setting the border width and relief of the frame and see whether it is actually gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your frame is actually disappearing it is just resize and that is why you cant see it. Add `Rf.pack_propagate(False)` to your frame it will prevent the frame from resizing when a new widget is added.

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("ABC")

Rf=Frame(root,width=100, height=800, bg="black")
Rf.pack_propagate(False)
Rf.pack(side=RIGHT)

Lf=Frame(root,width=1500, height=800, bg="green")
Lf.pack(side=LEFT)

b1 = Button (Rf, text= "Load", fg= "red", bg="black")
b1.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```